# Browse for folder in Windows 8 apps?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8

I am trying my hand at writing an app for Windows 8.

I want to add an input box where it allows the user to browse their files/folders and select a folder, whereupon I will search its contents. All I need is to add the input box and button "browse" that will allow me to look at a users files.

How could I add this simple XAML construct to my program?

Comment: Why can't u just drag it onto the designer?

Comment: I understand how the positioning and everything works. I don't know what the item I need to look at my file system tree is called :)

Comment: @ColeJohnson Why have you downvoted this? It is a legitimate question?

Comment: No. Not textbox. Textbox does not add the functionality that allows the user to browse their file system for files?

Comment: You would need a TextBox with a button. Hook the button click event to load a OpenFileDialog

Comment: @SimonKiely, your question says "How could I add this simple XAML construct..." The only parts of this that would be XAML are the textbox and button; file pickers are invoked from code, not XAML. But from your comments, it sounds like it's the folder picker that you're having trouble with, not the XAML. You might want to edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only access certain file locations in a Metro style app. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx) for a description.  You can allow the user to select a file using the [File Picker Contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771180.aspx).  As for how to do a textbox and a button, see [Create your first Metro Style app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974581.aspx) for an end to end example.